# How do use .htaccess on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS? php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

I'm a novice. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.2 and I've created an `.htaccess` file in the directory `/var/www/example.com/.htaccess`. But my script `hello.php` isn't working, and is instead returning `error 500 internal server error`.

First Step :

```
1. enabling mod-rewrite using 
sudo a2enmod rewrite

2. change config
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

3. restart apache2
sudo service apache2 restart

4. create .htaccess in sub folder
sudo nano /var/www/example.com/.htaccess
```

I want .htaccess hidden .php such as `"www.example.com/aaa.php"` to `"www.example.com/aaa/"`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Comment: When you receive a `500 Internal Server Error`, you can check your Apache error logs to typically find a more detailed account of what's happening.

Comment: Sometimes the access permission too causes such 500 internal server erors in ubuntu... Goto terminal and "cd" into your www directory and Try doing "sudo chmod 755 -R example.com" and try if it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try a few things. First, you're not including the trailing slash in your redirect. Second, the `-f` check against the `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` variable isn't going to work because it's fuzzy and will handle path info. So try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```